# Time Complexity and Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, space-complexity

My algorithm is as shown below. It makes a remote call to a server and gets the results process them and again send the remote call to a system. Can you give me an idea what can be time and space complexity of this algorithm?

```
Get search keyword from user
ϕ := getInfoFromConceptNet(keyword) // makes remote call
e := expandConcepts(ϕ)
expConcepts := {} // adds to an array
for each ec in e // first loop
expConcepts.add(ec) // adds to array
α= expandConcept(ec) //remote call
expConcepts.add(α) // adds to array
αkeywords=getKeywords(α) // calls a function to remove stopwords
for each αkw in αkeywords // second loop
Ω= expandConcept(αkw) // makes remote call
expConcepts.add(Ω) // adds to an array
results[ ]=performsearch(expConcepts,additional information) // searches the array
```

Comment: Can you properly indent your for loops? I can't figure out the indentation even in your original post. I only edit it to remove extra spaces to make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your second loop is nested into first? If yes, the complexity analysis given below stands for your algorithm.

Time and space complexity of this algorithm depends on implementations of `expandConcept()`, `getKeywords()`, `add()` and `performsearch()` functions. For the `add()`, time and space complexity may be `O(1)` if just appends its argument to the expConcepts array front index. Assumed that `performsearch()` performs binary search, which has an `O(logN)` (`N`: number of expConcepts elements), time complexity and constant space complexity, and an additional `O(M*(expandConcept() time-comp)*K*(expandConcept() time-comp))` (`M`: cardinal number of set e, `K`: cardinal number of akeywords), you have a **`O(M*(expandConcept time-comp)*K*(expandConcept() time-comp)*logN)`** time complexity. Space complexity depends on `expandConcepts()` space complexity.